# sequelize, query property on array of objects

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have looked extensively for an answer but could not find a simple solution.

I have a table that contains a column `subscriptionHistory`

The data can look like so:

```
[
  {
    "fromDate": "2023-01-24T10:11:57.150Z",
    "userSubscribedToo": "EuuQ13"
  },
  {
    "fromDate": "2022-01-24T10:11:57.150Z",
    "tillDate": "2022-02-24T22:59:59.999Z",
    "userSubscribedToo": "a4ufoAB"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to find the records of the subscriptions.

In Mongo we do

```
'subscriptionHistory.$.userSubscribedToo' = 'a4ufoAB'
```

Nice and easy.

I'm using PostgreSQL and Sequelize,

The following doesn't work.

```
const totalEarnings = await SubscriptionToken.count({
  where: {
    'subscriptionHistory.$.userSubscribedToo': user.id,
  },
});
```

Neither do any direct queries

```
SELECT *
FROM vegiano_dev."subscription-tokens"
WHERE "subscriptionHistory"->>'userSubscribedToo' = 'a4ufoAB'
--WHERE "subscriptionHistory" @> '{"userSubscribedToo": "a4ufoAB"}'
```

Not sure where to go now :-/

Comment: What is the column type of ```subscriptionHistory```?

Comment: @vicki JSONB type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JSON path condition with the `@@` (exists) [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
select *
from vegiano_dev."subscription-tokens"
where "subscriptionHistory" @@ '$[*].userSubscribedToo == "a4ufoAB"'
```

The `@>` will work as welll, but because `subscriptionHistory` is an array, you need to use an array with that operator:

```
where "subscriptionHistory" @> '[{"userSubscribedToo": "a4ufoAB"}]'
```

This assumes that `subscriptionHistory` is defined as `jsonb` which it should be. If it's not, you need to cast it: `"subscriptionHistory"::jsonb`